# Working example or tutorial for setting up webpack, coffeescript, mocha?

Tags: testing, webpack, coffeescript, mocha.js

I have a coffeescript project that started out as a mish-mash of gulp, rollup and babel.

I have converted it to build under webpack using coffee-loader and that  works really nicely.

However ... how do I get my coffee/mocha tests to run smoothly under webpack? The mocha-loader docs are very terse. I imagine it is quite straightforward to get *.test.coffee to load, compile coffee -> es6 and run as a test suite.

But it is sort of non-obvious - to me anyway.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It took a bit of work but I have this working in [a tiny demo project](https://github.com/tonyxyz/webpack-coffee-mocha-demo).

If you're looking to solve the same problem I hope this helps.